# How to delete puppet from CentOS7 on ec2

Tags: unix, server, google-cloud-platform, puppet, centos7

How to do a full removing of puppet server, agents from CentOs 7?
I am facing with some confusing part..
I tried so far:

```
rm -rf /etc/puppet
```

and

```
rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet
```

but no chance..

Comment: Did you try uninstalling "sudo yum remove puppet" ? And the files that remains can be removed manually.

Comment: You can follow this [puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.3/installing/uninstalling.html#uninstall-component-nodes) to remove all the traces of node

Comment: Which cloud product?

Comment: @KarthickN I tried..

Comment: @DanCornilescu Google

Comment: Compute Engine? Appe Engine Flex?

Comment: @DanCornilescu 
Compute Engine.. thanks for the help

Comment: @DanCornilescu Check your Twitter, please

Comment: After you get your desired setup maybe consider creating a custom image to use on subsequent instances, if so desired: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The puppet-enterprise-uninstaller script is installed on the master, and in a split install, on the PuppetDB and console nodes. In order to uninstall, you must run the uninstaller on each component node.

By default, the uninstaller removes the software, users, logs, cron jobs, and caches, but it leaves your modules, manifests, certificates, databases, and configuration files in place, as well as the home directories of any users it removes.

The *nix agent package doesn't include the uninstaller, so you must take additional steps to uninstall from agent nodes.

On the master, navigate to `/opt/puppetlabs/bin/` and copy `puppet-enterprise-uninstaller` to the agent node you want to uninstall. 
On the agent node, run the installer: `sudo ./puppet-enterprise-uninstaller`
Follow prompts to uninstall.
(Optional) If you plan to reinstall on the node at a later date, remove the agent certificate for the agent from the master:

```
 puppet cert clean <AGENT CERT NAME>
```